# RESTful API Suggestions

Tags: .net, ruby-on-rails, api, rest

I'm about to create an API for a existing .NET application and want to go the RESTful service route. Our backend platform is .NET and MSSQL. I'm hoping for a good blend or scalability combined with clean architecture.

Are there any strong opinions on the best way to implement a RESTful .NET API (WCF, standard ASP.NET, MVC or even HTTP Listener)?

Also any opinions on why NOT to go with .NET or reasons to use something like RoR.

Thanks in advance for any opinions on this topic.

Comment: Update: I went with a HTTPListner using a UriTemplateTable and it's been great. full control over everything with excellent performance.

Comment: Life is so easy with HttpListener, isn't it?  I've been using it for the last year and I couldn't be happier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.openrasta.com  It is the only .Net framework that will help you learn how to create a REST api.  You can do it with other frameworks but unless you have experience building REST apis you will likely be led astray.

Answer (score 0):

One option is WCF Data Services formerly known as ADO.NET Data Services which has some REST qualities to its implemention.

It is easy to create a basic service from an Entity Framework model of the database.  From there service operations can be added for additional capabilities.